# Entity Framework: how to implement shared primary key with Fluent API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

I have two tables and want to use PK of one of them in another one as PK.

This is my implementation with data annotation:

```
public class User
{
    public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public System.Guid StudentId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // shared primary key 
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Here `Student` table uses `User`'s primary key.

**How can I implement this with Fluent API?**

(As a second question, if I delete a value from `Student` table, will accur a cascade delete?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I implement this with Fluent API?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.User)
    .WithOptional();
```

> if I delete a value from Student table, will accur a cascade delete.

No, because `Student` is the dependent in the relationship (it carries the foreign key) and not the principal (which is `User`). Cascading delete is only in effect if you delete the principal. For a one-to-one relationship you have to enable it manually though:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.User)
    .WithOptional()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Now, if a `User` gets deleted the related `Student` (if there is any) will be deleted as well.